# How to get a date format 'Fri Jun 17th, 2022' using JavaScript new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);

Tags: javascript

I need the day written in ordinal US-English form (1st, 2nd, 3rd, ..., 31st) and not (1, 2, 3, ..., 31)

tried:

```
const options = {
        weekday: "short",
        year: "numeric",
        month: "short",
        day: "numeric",
      };
const hoje = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
```

expected: "Thu, Jan 4th, 2024"
resulted: "Thu, Jan 4, 2024"

Comment: If you use moment.js, it has a simple way of displaying/parsing dates. See this for more info: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Answer (score 0):

When we want to format dates in JavaScript with ordinal suffixes (like "1st", "2nd", "3rd", etc.), we need create custom logic because the standard toLocaleDateString method does not support ordinal day formats.

I have a function for it, hope that works:

```
function formatDateWithOrdinal(date) {
    const options = { weekday: 'short', year: 'numeric', month: 'short' };
    const day = date.getDate();
    let daySuffix;

    switch (day) {
        case 1:
        case 21:
        case 31:
            daySuffix = 'st';
            break;
        case 2:
        case 22:
            daySuffix = 'nd';
            break;
        case 3:
        case 23:
            daySuffix = 'rd';
            break;
        default:
            daySuffix = 'th';
    }

    return `${date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options)} ${day}${daySuffix}`;
}

// Usage
const today = new Date();
console.log(formatDateWithOrdinal(today));
```